# Prevent ImageButton from resizing with source image

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I have a problem with my ImageButton because it appears to be resizing together with the source image. This is quite problematic because I'm using a TableLayout with equally weighted TableRows to achieve a uniform grid layout but for some reason, that particular ImageButton is resizing itself with the image and making that entire row appear bigger than the others even if they all have the same layout weight.

empty src:
https://gyazo.com/b50ab6d7afb6608db0505d701a2a40c9

with src, adjustViewBounds=true
https://gyazo.com/e2a2dae581d1fae4503b6e130ced776d

with src, adjustViewBounds=false
https://gyazo.com/2623f08fcffea586d5b7917332ae7291

XML Tag:

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/stat_analyze"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/sp2_calc_button"
                    android:onClick="btnClicked"
                    android:src="@drawable/statistics_white"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Update:
So far, I've tried replacing the source image which is a png with a smaller version and with an android vector resource replacement but so far, I've still been stuck with the same results. I guess that means the only way to do this really is to lock the layout height. I've tried programatically setting the height at runtime but I still get the same result.

Update:
I tried once again, resizing the image to a fixed value. I noticed, however, that this particular button does not take up the whole area until it reaches a height quite far beyond the intended height. What I mean by this is for example, I set it to 60dp, the entire row will already begin to take up more space even if the button itself hasn't matched the parent height yet. I don't know why this is happening as this is the first time I've seen this happen. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the  `scaleType` **fitXY** attribute:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Yeah, I have and it produces the same result.

Comment: Try the setting the height with some static value like 70dp instead of match_parent.

Comment: I need it as match_parent though because I want it to maintain a uniform height.

Comment: then try making it static in the root  of the imagebutton

Comment: The view which is parent to the imagebutton

Comment: I mean what do you mean making it static? Make the height of the image static?

Comment: No the height of the parent view of the imagebutton

Comment: The parent view of the ImageView is a TableRow. Its height is determined by layout weight. In the hierarchy of the views, I don't think I can make any of them static. Would there be some other way to address this without making one of the heights of the views static?